# Next-auth. Login User then what?

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, user-management, next-auth

After I have logged in a user with next-auth, how I do fetch data using their information? Do I keep calling useSession or do something else? I want to fetch data on each page but this appears impossible become of the async nature of useSession() on each page

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you can use the access token provided to you by the OAuth provider to further authenticate against that provider and do other stuff, i.e. get the users Google Drive files, Google Contacts, etc. etc.

Check out this example where I do just that in a Next.js API route with Google Drive and NextAuth.js here: https://github.com/ndom91/newtelco-tab/blob/main/src/pages/api/gdrive.ts